# Jquery website seo optimisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

sorry to post a question that maybe already has been discussed , but I really need a basic explanation about the matter.. I am a beginner at programming (trying to learn here), like .. level 1, I did some web researching but I didn't achieved the expected result.
  What's all the fuss about? Well I have a one page loaded jquery scripted website and I would like for the google crawler to be able to see the links.
  So , these are the links of the website

```
               '<nav class="cbp-spmenu 
                cbp-spmenu-vertical       cbp-spmenu-left" id="cbp-spmenu-s2">
                <h3>Menu</h3>
                <a class="scroll" href="#home">Home</a>
                <a class="scroll" href="#features">Features</a>
                <a class="scroll" href="#screenshots">Screen Shots</a>
                <a class="scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                <a class="scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                <a class="scroll" href="#products">Products</a>
            </nav>


    and this would be the script for one of the links


<div id="services" class="banner-bottom">
<div class="container">
    <h4>Recommendations and awards by a number of our clients.</h4>
<!-- Slider-starts-Here -->
            <script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
             <script>
                // You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
                $(function () {
                  // Slideshow 4
                  $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
                    auto: true,
                    pager: false,
                    nav: false,
                    speed: 500,
                    namespace: "callbacks",
                    before: function () {
                     $('.events').append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
                    },
                    after: function () {
                      $('.events').append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
                    }
                  });

                });
              </script>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your site's layout HTML in an HTML file. Have the HTML file call your jquery instead of printing your whole website from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

First your website should be seo optimized, for this you can find [Website SEO Audit](https://websiteseostats.com/) online tool to verify and find out the suggestions that these tools provide to optimize your website page.

There are lot of factors you need to consider for SEO Optimization.

Use below format and interlink your pages one to another each and google crawler automatically find all links and index them naturally. These links are Dofollow links.

```
<a href="YourURL" title="title here">Your Text </a>
```